# How to import an implicit object?

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

Maybe this is a silly question, but compiling the following gives `error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Outer.Inner.MyImplicit[Int]`:

```
object Outer {
  import Inner._

  def someMethod[T : MyImplicit] = {}
  someMethod[Int]

  object Inner {
    sealed trait MyImplicit[T]
    implicit case object IntImplicit extends MyImplicit[Int]
  }
}
```

Why can't the `Outer` object see `IntImplicit` despite the import? Is there a way to have the compiler find the `IntImplicit` within the `Inner` object?

**Update**: What if I un-nested `Inner` — how would I import it then?

```
object Outer {
  import Other._
  def someMethod[T : MyImplicit] = {}
  someMethod[Int]
}

object Other {
  sealed trait MyImplicit[T]
  implicit case object IntImplicit extends MyImplicit[Int]
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define the object Inner before you import it. So, this works just fine.

```
object Outer {
  object Inner {
    sealed trait MyImplicit[T]
    implicit case object IntImplicit extends MyImplicit[Int]
  }
  import Inner._

  def someMethod[T : MyImplicit] = {}
  someMethod[Int]
}
```

Comment: @Sergey Any idea how I would do it if I instead had a separate (non-nested) object?  (See the update)

Comment: I'll add that the order doesn't matter when you have an explicit signature: `implicit val IntImplicit: MyImpicit[Int] = new MyImplicit[Int] {}`. But there is no way to put one on `case object`.

Comment: For the update: again, if they are in a single file, `Other` has to go before `Outer` _or_ have an exact return type for `IntImplicit`. Otherwise `Other` isn't typechecked yet, so the compiler hasn't figured out that `IntImplicit` is a `MyImplicit[Int]`.